# Iterate the Array with in Array using dust.js

Tags: dust.js

```
[
    [
         "x1", "x2" , 
         [
            ["n1", "n2"],["x3", "x4"],["x5", "x6"]
         ]
    ],
    [
         "y1", "y2"
    ],
    [
        "z1", "z2"
    ]
]
```

I want to access the x3 and x4 items , how to access with dustjs

Answer (score 2):

It mostly depends on what you mean by "access", but here are some example templates that show you what happens if you use the special `.` reference, which in Dust means "the current iteration context"

```
{#.}
  Item {.} 
{/.}
```

Output:

```
Item x1,x2,n1,n2,x3,x4,x5,x6 Item y1,y2 Item z1,z2
```

By iterating one level into the current context, you see that the top-level array elements are iterated on. One step deeper:

```
{#.}{#.}
  Item {.} 
{/.}{/.}
```

Output:

```
Item x1 Item x2 Item n1,n2,x3,x4,x5,x6 Item y1 Item y2 Item z1 Item z2
```

Notice how the depth at which we traverse nested arrays increases the more levels of context you tell Dust to inspect. So for your above example, four levels will suffice:

```
{#.}{#.}{#.}{#.}
  Item {.} 
{/.}{/.}{/.}{/.}
```

Output:

```
Item x1 Item x2 Item n1 Item n2 Item x3 Item x4 Item x5 Item x6 Item y1 Item y2 Item z1 Item z2
```